# security-constraint not getting applied

Tags: security, web.xml

I have found below configuration.

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection> 
            <web-resource-name>DisabledMethods</web-resource-name>
              <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
              <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
              <http-method>PUT</http-method>
               <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
              <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>empty_role</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

In this case the Trace method is still allowed for all the users. How to block HTTP trace method? Please help. I am new to this.

Comment: Does the `url-pattern` `domain.com/*` match `domain.com` ?

Comment: We are using our system on intranet. So no domain is used...